# splitting a single row into multi rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [query to display a row data as column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630256/query-to-display-a-row-data-as-column)

hi i have a  single row holding data as  1,2,10,4,5,6,7,8,13,16,17,3.
I need a query to split them into sequence row. such that 1 should appear in 1st row, 2 in second row, 10 in third row................

Comment: Haha, now you get why it is good to normalize the data? ;-)

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way of doing it. Rows are columns are two very different concepts in relational databases, and if you need a conversion between them then something is wrong with your design.

Comment: 3 questions, all seem to be asking the same in different ways. Why don't you edit one of your originals and post a proper question probably with more details?

Answer (score 2):

Use [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) to make your comma separated string into a xml. Then you can use [cross apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) to get the [nodes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) of the xml as rows and use the [value()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) function to get the node value.

```
declare @Str varchar(100) = '1,2,10,4,5,6,7,8,13,16,17,3'

select 
  r.value('.', 'int') as Val
from (select cast('<r>'+replace(@Str, ',', '</r><r>')+'</r>' as xml)) as x(x)
  cross apply
    x.nodes('r') as r(r)
```

If you need to use this for a table instead of a variable you can have a look here. [How to split repeating string delimated by commas in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618305/how-to-split-repeating-string-delimated-by-commas-in-t-sql/5618419#5618419)

Comment: You may also need to replace `&` with `&amp;` in the source column to avoid an XML error if using this technique on a different dataset.